# Read data in two columns and print values if it contains NULL or Whitspaces

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, columns

How can I read data separated by space in two columns and print value from column-1 that may contains Null or empty value next to it in columns-2 into a file, otherwise perform action if it has values in both columns:

data set:

```
User Numbers
u1 12   
u3 45
u3 20
u4 5
u5 
u6 7
u7 32
u8 
u9 10
u10 14
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with awk, for example. The variables `$1` and `$2` contain the text of the columns, and `NR` contains the number of columns.

```
awk '
    NR == 1 {print "Only one column: " $1}
    NR == 2 {print "The sum of the two columns is", $1 + $2}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks bunch for your answer... I tried your answer and some part did work... except the Column-1 was showing incorrect User for value in column-2. I ended up putting my head around it and created something like this:

## !/bin/bash

while IFS= read -a line; do
  COL1=$(printf "%s\n" "${line[@]}" | awk '{print $1}')
  COL2=$(printf "%s\n" "${line[@]}" | awk '{print $2}')
  SRCH1=$(ldapsearch "(uid=${COL1})" | grep uid: | awk '{print $2}')
  SRCH2=$(ldapsearch "(uid=${COL1})" | grep initials: | awk '{print $2}')
  SRCH3=${SRCH2}
  if [ "$COL1" = "$SRCH1" -a "$COL2" = "$SRCH2" ]; then
    echo "UID: $SRCH1"
    echo "INITIALS: $SRCH2"
  else
    echo "NO UID: $COL1"
    echo "NO INITIALS: $COL2"
  fi
done < datafile8